# Selecting the first elements of element groups using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given the following XML document:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>1</id>
    <a1>0</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>1</id>
    <a1>0</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>2</id>
    <a1>0</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>2</id>
    <a1>0</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

The XML elements `bar` are list elements, logically grouped by type and id. The sample document therefore contains two ordered lists (type=1 and id=1, and type=1 and id=2) with two elements each. In the real document there are many more lists (using different types and ids) of various length.

Now I need to update the first element `a1` of each list with a different value, resulting e.g. in the following document:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>1</id>
    <a1>-100</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>1</id>
    <a1>0</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>2</id>
    <a1>-100</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <type>1</type>
    <id>2</id>
    <a1>0</a1>
    <other_stuff/>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

In pseudo SQL this would likely look like this:

```
update bar set a1 = -100 where position() = 1 group by type, id
```

Is this possible with XSLT 1.0? I think it boils down to being able to write an XPath expression giving the same result as my pseudo SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) to identify the first item in each group and change the child, copy the rest with the identity transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="new-value" select="-100"/>

    <xsl:key name="group" match="bar" use="concat(type, '|', id)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bar[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(type, '|', id))[1])]/a1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$new-value"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for further explanation, the key definition `<xsl:key name="group" match="bar" use="concat(type, '|', id)"/>` lets the XSLT processor index the `bar` elements on the `concat(type, '|', id)` so that we can use the key function with e.g. `key('group', '1|1')` to find all the `bar` elements with that value for `concat(type, '|', id)`.

You only want to change the first `bar` element in each group so we need to have a way to identify that first item inside of a predicate to `bar[...]` where we need to find a pattern that expresses the condition

```
bar[. is the first item in its group]
```

The group we get inside the pattern with `key('group', concat(type, '|', id))`, so we want to write a condition

```
bar[. is the first item in key('group', concat(type, '|', id))]
```

which we can express nearly literally in XSLT 2.0 with the `is` operator and the pattern

```
bar[. is key('group', concat(type, '|', id))[1]]
```

With XSLT 1.0 we can express it using generate-id, as done in

```
bar[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(type, '|', id))[1])]
```

which selects/matches those `bar` element for which the generated id is equal to the generated id of the first (`[1]`) item in the group computed by `key('group', concat(type, '|', id))`.

Comment: Just for my understanding: The `xsl:key` generates a key for all `bar` elements using the string concatenation of the contents of the child elements `type` and ìd`. And the `generate-id(...)` function call then regenerates that key and checks if it matches the current element. This creates a list for each type, id pair, of which the first is then selected. Is this more or less correct?

Comment: @Markus, I have added some explanation about the used approach, I have taken a way through XSLT 2.0 as there the expression is easier to express and closer to natural language.